# Divide and Conquer algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, indexoutofboundsexception

I have to write an algorithm in Java that uses the
divide and conquer technique. Given an array V with n int elements
the algorithm should calculate the number of times that two consecutive 
0's appear.

Example :If `V = [3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]`, the algorithm should return 3,
Note that 0, 0, 0  corresponds to having 2 pairs of consecutive zeros.

I have written the program as below but when I run it it gives me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] v = {3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2};
        System.out.println(Conta_Zeri_Main(v));
    }

    public static int Conta_Zeri_Main(int[] v){
        if (v.length == 0 || v.length == 1)
            return 0;
        else  
            return Conta_Zeri(v, 1, v.length);
    }

    public static int Conta_Zeri(int[] v, int i, int f){
        int m,result,sx,dx;
        if (i >= f)
            return 0;
        else{
            m = (i + f)/2;
            sx = Conta_Zeri(v, i, m);
            dx = Conta_Zeri(v, m+1, f);
            result = sx + dx;
            if ((v[m] == v[m+1]) && (v[m] == 0))
                result++;

            return result; 
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find out. And give meaningful names to your variables to help all the readers, including yourself, understanding the code.

Comment: What line are you getting the exception?

Comment: Try adding this condition in your if, if ((m < f-1) && (v[m] == v[m+1]) && (v[m] == 0)), also, IMO starting value of i should be 0 and not 1.

Comment: I did what you said Abhishek. The program doesn't throw exception anymore but it gives an answer of 2 when it should give 3.

Comment: Peskillet, I'm getting the exception at  if ((v[m] == v[m+1]) && (v[m] == 0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the anomalies already pointed out,

In your code you do not check if `v[m] = v[m+1] = 0`. This will miss out some possibilities when the array is partitioned between 2 consecutive zeroes.

Change your if statement to:

```
if ( (m < v.length - 1 ) && (v[m] == v[m+1]) && (v[m] == 0) )
```